Ignite.reentrantlock throwing IgniteSpiExcetion when remote node is segmented
I have an Ignite cluster with 3 server nodes, 3 client nodes. (server node and client node runs in same JVM in different webapp).
Server nodes:

ign-1
ign-2
ign-3

To test split-cluster, I have blocked the outbound ports (57100-57510) on ign-1. It means ign-1 should be segmented from the cluster.
During this period, my code in ign-2 accessed IgniteLock via Ignite.reentantLock(s, true, true, true), but the tryLock is failed saying that remote node(ign-2) is not accessible.
Why this would happen?
Also, when we re-enabled the ports, all the nodes got segmented/isolated. Why this happening? It's happening on RHEL9.
Is this a bug?

2024-06-06 14:28:50,167 UTC+0530 WARN  [Thread-6] com.xxx.yyy.zzz.cluster.ignite.xxxxxxReentrantLock -- Lock@925268428[MODIFY(xxxxxx@1391314997@783)]; LockObj=com.xxx.yyy.zzz.cluster.ignite.ApacheIgniteClusterSpi@7891d711; Locks=[] retrieved exception during  tryLock(long, TimeUnit) of Thread[Thread-6,5,main] : class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to send message to remote node: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=49a2606e-3dbf-4b04-9f15-ff0df441a49b, consistentId=ign-1, addrs=ArrayList [10.194.42.86, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [Ign-1.otxlab.net/10.194.42.86:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1717664022117, loc=false, ver=2.16.0#20231215-sha1:7bde6a42, isClient=false]
org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to send message to remote node: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=49a2606e-3dbf-4b04-9f15-ff0df441a49b, consistentId=ign-1, addrs=ArrayList [10.194.42.86, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [Ign-1.otxlab.net/10.194.42.86:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1717664022117, loc=false, ver=2.16.0#20231215-sha1:7bde6a42, isClient=false]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1152) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1052) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2101) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2194) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1279) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.proceedMapping0(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:1236) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.proceedMapping(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:1176) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.map0(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:1164) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.map(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:923) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.mapOnTopology(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:890) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.map(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:819) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedCache.lockAllAsync(GridDhtColocatedCache.java:718) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.GridDistributedCacheAdapter.txLockAsync(GridDistributedCacheAdapter.java:110) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal.getAllAsync(GridNearTxLocal.java:2186) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedCache$1.op(GridDhtColocatedCache.java:206) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$AsyncOp.op(GridCacheAdapter.java:5611) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.asyncOp(GridCacheAdapter.java:4436) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedCache.getAsync(GridDhtColocatedCache.java:204) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:4682) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.repairableGet(GridCacheAdapter.java:4648) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:1331) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProxyImpl.get(GridCacheProxyImpl.java:352) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$4.applyx(DataStructuresProcessor.java:743) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor$4.applyx(DataStructuresProcessor.java:738) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor.retryTopologySafe(DataStructuresProcessor.java:1893) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor.getAtomic(DataStructuresProcessor.java:738) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.DataStructuresProcessor.reentrantLock(DataStructuresProcessor.java:1560) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.reentrantLock(IgniteKernal.java:3042) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at com.opentext.ecm.asm.cluster.ignite.ApacheIgniteClusterSpi.getLock(ApacheIgniteClusterSpi.java:639) ~[jds.jar:?]
at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.cluster.ignite.xxxxxxReentrantLock.tryLock(JdsSimpleMapReentrantLock.java:251) ~[jds.jar:?]
at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.dbtransaction.SimpleReentrantLock.acquire(SimpleReentrantLock.java:91) ~[jicsdb_intf.jar:?]
at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.dbtransaction.SimpleReentrantLock.acquire(SimpleReentrantLock.java:67) ~[jicsdb_intf.jar:?]
at com.xxx.yyy.asm.dbtransaction.JdsDbObject._acquireWriteLocks(JdsDbObject.java:1733) ~[jicsdb_intf.jar:?]
at
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node due to unrecoverable exception (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=49a2606e-3dbf-4b04-9f15-ff0df441a49b, addrs=[Ign-1.otxlab.net/10.194.42.86:47100, /127.0.0.1:47100], err= class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote node does not observe current node in topology : 49a2606e-3dbf-4b04-9f15-ff0df441a49b]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:625) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:693) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1181) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:691) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.createCommunicationClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:442) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.reserveClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:231) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1105) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
... 45 more
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Remote node does not observe current node in topology : 49a2606e-3dbf-4b04-9f15-ff0df441a49b
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createNioSession(GridNioServerWrapper.java:502) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:693) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1181) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.createTcpClient(GridNioServerWrapper.java:691) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.createCommunicationClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:442) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool.reserveClient(ConnectionClientPool.java:231) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:1105) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
... 45 more
...

